# Could I materialize electricity making my own lighting?

Tags: electricity

Where does electricity come from? It comes from very little charged particles inside every atom of materials. Electricity occurs when these little pieces move from one atom to another inside the material.

I found this definition, so according to that we are surrounded by little charged particles of atoms.

Could I create my own lighting?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil

Comment: Shuffle your feet on a synthetic carpet or a while, then touch a tap or doorknob. The resulting spark is lightning (in miniature).

Comment: Lighting or lightning?

Answer (score 0):

> I found this definition, so according to that we are surrounded by little charged particles of atoms.

These little particles are called electrons and they are trapped around the  positive nuclei of the atoms.

> Could I create my own lighting?

Yes. Bicycles use dynamos to light the road at night. There exist [hand held flashlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanically_powered_flashlight) that utilize muscle power.

> a flashlight that is powered by electricity generated by the muscle power of the user, so it does not need replacement of batteries, or recharging from an electrical source. There are several types which use different operating mechanisms. They use different motions to generate the required power; such as squeezing a handle, winding a crank, or shaking the flashlight itself.

```
 ....
```

> A dyno torch, [dynamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo) torch or squeeze flashlight is a flashlight or pocket torch which stores energy in a flywheel. The user repeatedly squeezes a handle to spin a flywheel inside the flashlight, attached to a small dynamo, supplying electrical current to an incandescent bulb or light-emitting diode. The flashlight must be pumped continuously during use, with the flywheel turning the generator between squeezes to keep the light going continuously.